# Uploading static assets to S3 in postinstall step on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out the best flow for how to upload my static assets to S3.

The current solution serves our static assets via our Heroku application, which is getting quite expensive and slow. I would like to offload these to AWS.

My setup is:

1. Node.js application which generates a folder named `static/` which would need to be offloaded somewhere (e.g. S3) during the `npm install` step
2. CircleCI runs our continuous integration which gives the green light to pull requests on Github.

I would like to upload the assets in the `postinstall` script of the Heroku deployment (to make sure we upload the correct tagged hashed versions to S3).

Is this a good idea? Also, can I invoke the AWS CLI from a Heroku `package.json` `postinstall` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better and recommended way is to use Amazon CloudFront. It reads static assets from your web server and caches it, so you don't need any scripts to upload your assets. The only thing you need to change is to set host in your asset urls to cloudfront distribution.

You can read more about it here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

Comment: Thanks! I definitely made things a bit overcomplicated.